# VueJs + webpack Simple - build - asset files missing

Tags: webpack, build, vuejs2

I am using Vue-cli with the webpack-simple to create a small app.

In the assets folder, by default is the logo.png. There I add an main.css file - and link it I the **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

On the localhost works great, but when I build the app in terminal (npm run build) -> Is creating a /dist folder. If i take this folder and the index.html and put it on the web, the CSS file is not working. HOW can I make it work?? Because I want to add more folders (like custom js - /js/some.js ; /css/media.css ;  etc)

Here is my **webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

I can't find the solution on any forum & Sry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

With `webpack-simple` by default the css is bundled together the built js, so you don't have to load it explicitly from `index.html`

Comment: And why when I put the index.html and the dist folder on server, the css is not working?